# Change text-color on div :hover

Tags: css, html

I can't seem to find how to change the text-color from black to white whenever I hover over the schedule over here http://apavtcongresso.staging.wpengine.com/

Scroll down to "PROGRAMA" and you'll find the schedule, it has a couple of tabs named "Day - 01, Day - 02" etc, inside there's black text that I wish to change to white whenever I hover over the tabs. I've already changed the :active color but I can't find the right classes to customize the css of hover, any help please?

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the body of your question. External links tend to break and cause confusion for future visitors to this question, and are thus not considered a good fit for Stack Overflow's Q&A format.

Comment: Using your developer tools in Chrome (Inspect element) should help you decipher where you need to look to be making changes to classes etc etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.your-div-class:hover, .your-div-class:focus {
    color: #fff;
}
```

*side note:* check in your code that .your-div-class or any class associated to its inner text hasn't a color assigned with !important, in that case either remove the !important or assign it to the hover too.

**EDIT:** try this:

```
.schedule-layout2 .schedule-nav li:hover .day-number {
color: #fff !important;
}
.schedule-layout2 .schedule-nav li:hover .schedule-date {
color: #fff !important;
}
```

Comment: I can make them turn white like this 

`.day-number:hover {
    color: #fff !important;
}

.schedule-date:hover {
    color: #fff !important;
}`

but only when I hover over the text and not over the tab, which is what I'm trying to do

Comment: edited with your code, tell me if it works like that

Comment: I tried directly modifying the style.css on your website, with the code i edited in my answer, and it works

Comment: Okay, doing `.nav-tabs:hover div {
    color: #fff !important;
}` gets me the white color on hover, but now it changes to white in every tab and not only on the :hover one.

Comment: Yep, it works like a charm with your edited code, thanks a bunch! :)

Comment: Careful if you use the same nav tabs on another page since we using the class .schedule-layout2 that is probably specifically linked to the page you pointed? in case you can try to remove it and see if it still works fine, not sure why you got downvoted for this question anyway glad it helped

Comment: Simple questions trigger the downvoters... :) Thanks!